# Programmatically View image hash values

Tags: c#, php

How to Programmatically View image hashes in C# or PHP ?

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "image hashes"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean "get the hash of an Image file":

In C#, you can use the [`MD5CryptoServiceProvider` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.md5cryptoserviceprovider.aspx) to calculate an MD5 hash. Here's an example function that uses this class and a filename to accomplish what you want (thanks to [this page](http://sharpertutorials.com/calculate-md5-checksum-file/)):

```
public string GetMD5HashFromFile(string fileName)
{
   FileStream file = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open);
   MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
   byte[] retVal = md5.ComputeHash(file);
   file.Close();

   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   for (int i = 0; i < retVal.Length; i++)
   {
     sb.Append(retVal[i].ToString("x2"));
   }
   return sb.ToString();
}
```

For PHP, you can just use the [`md5_file()` function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.md5-file.php), e.g.:

```
$file = 'MyImage.jpg';

$hash = md5_file($file);
```

Note that both of these examples will work for any file type, not just image files.

Answer (score 3):

In PHP you can simply use `sha1_file()` or [`hash_file()`](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.hash-file.php) for better algos.